# Loading datagridview in VB.NET programmatically using dataset

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, dataset, populate

I've created a datagridview, `dataGridReport` in the Designer view of VB 2010.
I'm then using a query to fill a dataset, and I want this dataset to populate the datagridview... but it doesn't seem to work.

This is my code:

```
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
                         Data Source=C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\MenuDB.accdb"
con.Open()
Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
Dim adapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim sql As String

sql = @"SELECT OrderDate, MenuItem 
        FROM   MenuItems, Orders 
        WHERE  Orders.itemID = MenuItems.ID 
           AND Format(Orders.OrderDate,'mm/dd/yyyy') >= #" + fromDate + "# 
           AND Format(Orders.OrderDate,'mm/dd/yyyy') <= #" + toDate + "#"

adapter.SelectCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, con)
adapter.Fill(ds)
dataGridReport.DataSource = ds
```

I know something's missing now - I've looked around and most people seem to use something like `dataGridReport.DataSource = ds.Tables('somereference')`

But mine is a dynamically created dataset from a query joining two tables, it's not something stored among the project Data Sources. I also haven't bound the datagridview to any datasource via its properties. What am I missing?

(By the way, the sql query is correct, I've tested it and returns expected results).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get the table from the data source via the index:

```
dataGridReport.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
```

Comment: I've tried that, but I get the error `DataBind is not a member of System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView`

Comment: Okay I retried it - I kept the first line you supplied but removed the second, and now it's working! Thanks a lot! If you edit your answer to remove the second line, I'll select it as the answer.

Comment: @user961627: funny thing - I was going to suggest that (i.e. remove DataBind), but you already figured. There is [no DataBind member for DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx). :)

Comment: @user961627 yes, you're right. I confused it with a third-party DataGrid control that needs to be explicitly bound.

Answer (score 1):

```
dataGridReport.DataSource = ds.Tables("Tablename")
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
DataSource=C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\MenuDB.accdb"
con.Open()
Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
Dim adapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim sql As String

sql = @"SELECT OrderDate, MenuItem 
      FROM   MenuItems, Orders 
      WHERE  Orders.itemID = MenuItems.ID 
      AND Format(Orders.OrderDate,'mm/dd/yyyy') >= #" + fromDate + "# 
      AND Format(Orders.OrderDate,'mm/dd/yyyy') <= #" + toDate + "#"

adapter.SelectCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, con)
adapter.Fill(ds,sql)
dataGridReport.DataSource = ds.tables(sql)
```